# Is this qualified as a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have to use this as a switch statement. This is a switch statement, right?

```
    if (dGrade > 93.99) {strFGrade= strA;}                              //A= above 94

    else if (dGrade >= 90.00 && dGrade <= 93.99 ) {strFGrade= strLA;}   //A- = 90-93.99

    else if (dGrade >= 87.70 && dGrade <= 89.99)  {strFGrade= strHB;}   //B+= 87.7-89.99

    else if (dGrade >= 83.33 && dGrade <= 87.69)  {strFGrade= strB;}    //B= 83.33-87.69

    else if (dGrade >= 80.00 && dGrade <= 83.32 ) {strFGrade= strLB;}   //B- = 80-83.32

    else if (dGrade >= 75.00 && dGrade <= 79.99 ) {strFGrade= strHC;}   //C+= 75-79.99

    else if (dGrade >= 70.00 && dGrade <= 74.99 ) {strFGrade= strC;}    //C= 70-74.99

    else if (dGrade >= 60.00 && dGrade <= 69.99 ) {strFGrade= strD;}    //D=60-69.99

    else    {strFGrade= strF;}                                          //F= below 60
```

Comment: No, a switch statement has special syntax, it isn't just a name for a type of if statement (but they are similar). See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: But to be fair, this code in its state cannot be directly converted into a switch command unless you use the completely pointless "switch(true)" antipattern.

Comment: While this cannot be converted into a `switch`, it doesn't mean it cannot be rewritten with less code.

Comment: This code is just begging to have a Java `enum` instead.

Comment: I'd like to point out too that this code is bugged and would not work well in a large production system.  What happens if `dGrade` has the value 83.325?  In this case strFGrade = strF.  Not fair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to test if a value lies in an interval like this with a switch-statement. Switch-statements have one branch for each individual value of a type, and the branch is taken if the value being switch on is *equal* to that of the branch.

That being said, it is possible to write your code in a bit more compact way like this:

```
if      (dGrade >= 94.00) strFGrade = strA;
else if (dGrade >= 90.00) strFGrade = strLA; 
else if (dGrade >= 87.70) strFGrade = strHB; 
else if (dGrade >= 83.33) strFGrade = strB;  
else if (dGrade >= 80.00) strFGrade = strLB; 
else if (dGrade >= 75.00) strFGrade = strHC; 
else if (dGrade >= 70.00) strFGrade = strC;  
else if (dGrade >= 60.00) strFGrade = strD;  
else strFGrade = strF;
```

The trick here is that you can leave out half of the tests because you have already tested that in an earlier if-statement. This does not take into account that values could lie *between* the limits of two different intervals in the original code.

The blocks (with `{` and `}`) are also not necessary here.

And note the conventional white space usage, with space on both sides of the `=`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a switch statement. Switch statement has the following structure:

```
switch (dgrade) {
  case 90:
    doSomething();
    break;
  case 100:
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
  default:
    do();
}
```

In your case you can't actually use a switch statement, since you have conditions, so you can only use `if-else` statements